# Execute coroutine from `call_soon` callback function

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I have following situation:

- Some internal class (which I have no control of) is executing my `callback` function using [call_soon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.call_soon).
- Within my `callback` I would like to call another courotune, but end up with "frozen" callback.

I will use modified [Hello World with call_soon()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#hello-world-with-call-soon) to demonstrate this:

```py
import asyncio

def hello_world(loop):
    print('Hello')
    # Call some coroutine.
    yield from asyncio.sleep(5, loop=loop)
    print('World')
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Schedule a call to hello_world()
loop.call_soon(hello_world, loop)

# Blocking call interrupted by loop.stop()
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

When I run this, nothing is being printed and the program never ends.

Ctrl+C

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../soon.py", line 15, in <module>
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1136, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/selectors.py", line 432, in select
    fd_event_list = self._epoll.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What is actually going on and why?

Any correct way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The example you mentioned demonstrate how to schedule a callback.

If you use the `yield from` syntax, the function is actually a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) and it has to be decorated accordingly:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def hello_world(loop):
    print('Hello')
    yield from asyncio.sleep(5, loop=loop)
    print('World')
    loop.stop()
```

Then you can schedule the coroutine as a task using [ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future):

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = hello_world(loop)
asyncio.ensure_future(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

Or equivalently, using [run_until_complete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=until_complete#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_until_complete):

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = hello_world(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

---

In two weeks, [python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0478/) will officially be released and you'll be able to use the new [`async`/`await`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) syntax:

```
async def hello_world(loop):
    print('Hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(5, loop=loop)
    print('World')
```

---

**EDIT**: It is a bit ugly, but nothing prevents you from creating a callback that schedules your coroutine:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = hello_world(loop)
callback = lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(coro)
loop.call_soon(callback)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

Comment: Yes, that I well understand. The problem is that I cannot change the way how `hello_world` is being called (using `call_soon`). I think that the only way to fix all this is to dig into _internal class_ and so it puts to `asyncio.Queue` then have consumer to be a coroutine that reads from it.  **EDIT**  Oh yes I'm so tired with decorating every second method to make it a coroutine.

Comment: Indeed I can. Although perhaps ugly, still this is a working solution. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with scheduling a callback in this case. It seems the callback isn't getting called, why? I understand all the points about _how_ to switch to a coroutine, but I don't understand what's wrong with scheduling a callback.

Comment: @BrianBulkowski There's nothing wrong with scheduling a callback. But you can't use the `yield from` or `await` syntax within the callback, cause this would make it a coroutine, and coroutines should be scheduled as tasks using `asyncio.ensure_future` or `loop.create_task`.

Comment: @Vincent Ah! I have received some enlightenment! That makes all the sense in the world.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call_soon` to call a coroutine using the following syntax:

```
loop.call_soon(asyncio.async, hello_world(loop))
```

Comment: [`asyncio.async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async) is deprecated since 3.4.4. Use `ensure_future` now. And that's exactly what [Vincent's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32310323/923794) already covered.